SPSS - How to specify the order of factors in linear mixed models (MIXED) in SPSS syntax?
SPSS Output
I was running some linear mixed models for a clinical trial, using treatment assignment ("Group") and timepoint ("Visit") as the factors.
In the output, Visit=6 was set as the reference group by default. Is there any way to specify in the syntax that allows me to use Visit=1 as the reference instead?
I visited the IBM documentations (https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/spss-statistics/beta?topic=reference-mixed) but still couldn't figure it out. Any advice would be appreciated!
The workaround I could think of right now is to recode the variable like by taking 7 minus the original number (i.e. Visit = 7-Visit) but that could create confusion down the road so I don't really prefer this method.
